# run-time error when resizing vector

Tags: c++, linux, vector, console-application

When I run this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    vector<vector<char> > screen;
    char ch = 'a';
    unsigned col = 100, row = 100;
    if(screen.size() < (unsigned)row)
        screen.resize(row);
    if(screen[row - 1].size() < (unsigned)col)
        screen[row - 1].resize(col);
    screen[9][9] = ch;
    cout<< "hello";
    cout.flush();
}
```

`cout` does not print anything and I get this error:

```
Segmentation Fault (core dumped)
```

In linux. Is anything wrong in the program?

If `col` and `row` have lower numbers there's no problem.

Comment: Zero-indexing.  A 100x100 vector has 100 elements in each, from 0 to 99.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(screen[row - 1].size() < (unsigned)col)
    screen[row - 1].resize(col);
```

You're only resizing `screen[99]` here. `screen[9]` still has size `0`, which is why you can't access `screen[9][9]` (you could, however, access `screen[99][9]`).

Comment: yep. thanks. that is a short extract of a lager program I should examine that again.

Answer (score 3):

You're resizing `screen` to `row` elements, but then you access element `row` in it. `vector`s in C++ are, like arrays, 0-based, so valid indexes are `0...row-1`.

Same goes for the inner vectors and `col`.

The fact that it works for smaller numbers is an (unfortunate) mishap.

Comment: I changed the index before posting. Now it is fixed in question and the problem is not solved.